# setting language for reverse geocoding Gmaps v.3

Tags: google-maps, geocode

do anybody now how to set language for reverse geocoding php response ? (always set en)

```
**Here is the code**
<code>
$api_key = "***";

$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=49.8411860,30.1066580&output=json&sensor=true_or_false&key=' . $api_key.'&language=uk';

$data = @file_get_contents($url);

$jsondata = json_decode($data,true);

if(is_array($jsondata )&& $jsondata ['Status']['code']==200) {
      $addr = $jsondata ['Placemark'][0]['address'];
}

echo $addr;
</code>
**The Output is**

"L'va Tolstoho street, Bila Tserkva, Kyivs'ka oblast, Ukraine"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want English then change your URI variable language to 'en' i.e. &language=en

```
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=49.8411860,30.1066580&output=json&sensor=true_or_false&key=' . $api_key.'&language=en';
```

[Google Maps API Localization Reference Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization)

[See the list of all language codes on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)