# Setting language for reverse geocoding maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to set the language for geocoding reverse? the following code does not work:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.7127837,-74.00594130000002&sensor=false&language=pt-BR

The result always returns "New York" and not "Nova York" (pt-BR).

I set language=pt-BR, but it is being ignored. Is it bug?

PS: exists a question similar: [setting language for reverse geocoding Gmaps v.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815192/setting-language-for-reverse-geocoding-gmaps-v-3)

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work the way you expect. I wouldn't be suprised if this is by design though, it would be hard to know what parts of city/town/road names should be translated and which shouldn't.  I would expect it would work in Brazil though. [example](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-22.909926,-43.163254&sensor=false&language=pt-BR)

Comment: I think it is due to the lack of information in Google's database? if you look at the [Japanese result](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.7127837,-74.00594130000002&sensor=false&language=ja), you can see most of the places are in Japanese. Rather than a designed behavior, it seems more like lack of knowledge to me. Btw, [changing the domain to .br](https://maps.google.com.br/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.7127837,-74.00594130000002&sensor=false&language=pt-BR) does not seem to work.